# Jquery focusout doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to invoke method after losing focus, unfortunately my Jquery doesn't invoke .focusout method.

Code:

```js
$("#account-number").focusout(function() {
  console.log("number ready");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="form-group" id="number">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Account number</label>
    <input type="account-number" class="form-control" id="account-number" placeholder="1234 5678 1234 5678">
  </div>
</form>
```

script is linked properly, other JS functions are working.

Comment: code runs fine above. So what is different? Do you attach anything else to the element? Is jQuery finding the element?

Comment: Are you using any other libraries or frameworks in addition to jQuery?

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine. Are you waiting for $(document).ready?

Comment: Bootstrap, but even without it doesn't work. $("#account-number").ready(function() { console.log("hello);}); works, so it is just a problem with focusout

Comment: You should show us the exact code that you are using

Comment: It is super weird, codepen.io invokes jquery function correctly with my whole code, but my firefox browser doesn't.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bQLaZy my code, it works on codepen (though styling isn't perfect)

Comment: Did you try $("#account-number").blur(function() {
  console.log("number ready");
});

Comment: Yes, still no effect.

Comment: $(document).on("focusout","#account-number",function(){
    alert("fnumber ready");
}); 
Try that, and what happens if you try onchange?

Comment: Dear God, it works. But why my previous code didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following:

```
$(document).on("focusout","#account-number",function(){ alert("number ready"); });
```

Why this is happening? I do not know, but this is what I try when all else fails. I have read that this is actually logical and to be expected on input elements, but I cannot find the resource.